# PYTUBE module error

Tags: python, error-handling, pytube

Every time I try to use the PYTUBE module it shows this error.

```
from pytube import YouTube
ImportError: cannot import name 'YouTube'
```

Comment: Check if you have `pytube.py` in the current directory and rename it to something else.

Answer (score 3):

I think you did not install PyTube.

to check for that you can type that :

```
pip list | grep PyTube
```

If you found return as

> PyTube (0.1)

So you install PyTube if not you should install Pytube using

```
sudo pip install PyTube
```

or you can use

```
git clone https://github.com/nficano/pytube.git && cd pytube
setup.py build
sudo setup.py install
```

I hope to help

Answer (score 2):

```
pip uninstall pytube
```

and install pytube3 using 
`pip install pytube3`

Comment: Please explain the relevant difference between your answer and the older one by Amit Prafulla. Highlight the additional insight you provide.

Comment: he is asking to reinstall it mean pytube and i am saying use different version that is pytube3

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended to update pytube, I just fixed this error. Just uninstall the package using

```
pip uninstall pytube
```

and reinstall it, it should work as it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

try installing pytube3. it worked for me.

```
 pip install pytube3
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be mistakes in using which pip to install the package. There are both python 2 and 3 in my computer, and I am working with python3, so I use `pip3 install pytube3` instead of `pip install pytube3`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
pip uninstall pytube
```

and then

```
pip install pytube
```